# css html5 make div & text inside draggable & clickable

Tags: css, html

i have a div that i can drag but when i try to start dragging with cursor ON the text inside it does not drag, i have to click outside the text ive tried on opera and iron.

ive tried to add draggable=true wherever i can it still doesnt drag the text, can i make the text be in the background somehow?

i also want the div clickable so i put [a] here and there.

```
<a style='display:block;' href='?Q=$Q' draggable=true>
<div id='$Q' class='pdf' draggable=true ondragstart='drag(event)'>
   <a href='?Q=$Q'>pdf</a>
</div></a>
```

Comment: Your HTML is invalid and the font element was deprecated long ago and made obsolete in html5. Also, remove the echo stuff cause it has nothing to do with the problem, as well as the quotes for that.

Comment: Font is html4 i still use it for my development. I made it more readable.

Comment: font is deprecated in HTML4.01, too. The draggable attribute is HTML5.

Comment: It still works and is a old habit. I think the rest of the html is correct. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: why do you have two a tags?

Comment: I dont know the proper way of making the div a link, i think the first one is not very widely used, the second one is to make sure at least one works on different browsers.

Comment: you should have one a wrapper then style the text inside the div to replicate the behavoir of a regular link, however, this is a breaking standard in HTML 4 as you're not supposed to have block elements in inline elements. if you take out the inside a tag though you should be good in most browsers

Comment: hey I think it works thanks. I dont know of a better way of doing it to make div a link, besides [a] outside div, I wonder if there is.

Comment: it was because the a is only as big as the text inside instead of trying to form up to the actual div width (typical behavoir of inline items) as you're expecting.... so it wouldn't form to the size you're expecting it to. but the div (block element) would ... you can still put a inside, put display: block on it then width: 100%; height: 100%; line-height: 100%; in that case

Comment: you could also always put a click handler on the div instead of making it clickable with an anchor.... there's a lot of ways to do the behavior you want to replicate